# Download IBM Java JDK 8 for windows

Tags: java, windows, java-8, sdk, websphere

I am looking to Download IBM Java JDK 8 for windows 10 OS or Windows Server 2012 R2 OS.

Does IBM provide JAVA JDK 8 software so that we can install and test it?

Or

Does IBM provide only AIX and Linux supported IBM Java 8 installation software?

I referred the IBM page, it contains only AIX, Linux version of Java installation software.
https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/sdk8/

Answer (score 4):

[IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.80.doc/installing.html) says

> The SDK is available only as part of an IBM product.

Which means follow the links at the end of the page you linked from your question, download Eclipse, use the JDK that will be installed with Eclispe. Then, if you don't want Eclipse, delete it and keep the SDK.

OR

You can use [OpenJ9](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/), which is the JDK used by the IBM SDK.

As an aside I have to wonder why you need the IBM JDK in particular.

Comment: JDK installed in Eclipse supports Intel 32bit,

Reference: https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/sdk8/

OpenJ9 provides OpenJDK and openJ9 installation for Windows Server 2012 R2, 64 bit

Reference : https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/


but I am looking for is INTEL, Windows 10, 64 bit? 


I have requirement to test my application in IBM JDK 1.8.0_241.

Comment: Sorry, INTEL what? IBM JDK is not a thing anymore. Now it's OpenJ9 provided by the Eclipse foundation via Adopt OpenJDK.

Comment: Intel Core (I7) processor, Windows 10, 64 bit --> with this combination I am looking for IBM JDK. But in the portal AMD 64 bit, Windows --> combination JDK is provided.

Comment: That's the one you want. AMD 64 in this case simply means the x86_64 architecture, which also include Intel Core.